# How to go inside For Loop only if condition is PROCESSED

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, for-loop, drop-down-menu

I have a `MultipleDropdownlist` from where a User can select multiple Items.

Now what I want is, the condition should go inside the `FOR LOOP` only if the items selected from the `dropdownlist` is `PROCESSED`

Below is my code.

```
DataTable dtspmonthyear = new DataTable();
            ObjPriCon.Open();

            var selectedItemstest = cmbEmp_Name.Items.Cast<ListItem>().Where(x => x.Selected).Select(x => x.Value).ToArray();

            var resulttest = String.Join(",", selectedItemstest);
            var count = selectedItemstest.Length;
            str_emp_sel = resulttest;

            using (SqlConnection conn  = new SqlConnection("ConnectionString"))
            {
                using (SqlCommand sqcmd = new SqlCommand("select  month(a.dt_of_leave)month, year(a.dt_of_leave)year   " +
                                        "from emp_mst a where month(a.dt_of_leave) >= month(getdate())-1  and   " +
                                        "year(a.dt_of_leave)= case when  month(getdate())=1   " +
                                        "then year(getdate())-1 else year(getdate()) end  " +
                                        "and emp_card_no IN (" + str_emp_sel + ") order by emp_name", ObjPriCon))
                {
                    SqlDataAdapter damonthyear = new SqlDataAdapter(sqcmd);
                    damonthyear.Fill(dtspmonthyear);



                    for (i = 0; i < dtspmonthyear.Rows.Count; i++)
                    {
                        CF.ExecuteQuerry("exec Emp_Resign_Allocate_Leave '" + str_emp_sel + "','" + dtspmonthyear.Rows[0]["month"].ToString() + "', '" + dtspmonthyear.Rows[0]["year"].ToString() + "'");
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: Just wrap it in an `if` statement

Comment: @p.s.w.g: thanks but on which `condition` should I check the `IF` statement here ?

Comment: Why don't you just add a `where` clause to your SQL query? As a very important aside, you should really, really look at parameterized SQL to avoid [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com) - and `using` statements for your `SqlConnection` and `SqlCommand`. I'd also strongly suggest looking up .NET naming conventions.

Comment: @JonSkeet: Yes, will surely use the `using` statement for the query. But my main concern is to get the `PROCESSED` part in my `IF` condition. any idea how to achieve that ?

Comment: I'm guessing `selectedItemstest` contains the set of selected items that you're interested in. I can't be sure of its data type, but it might be something like this `if (selectedItemstest.Cast<EmpInfo>().Any(x => x.Status  == "PROCESSED")`

Comment: @p.s.w.g: `selectedItemtest` gives me the number of items selected from the dropdownlist. Also what is `Cast<EmpInfo>` as it is giving error as that it is a method which is not valid in given contest.

Comment: You still haven't explained why you don't just put the condition into your SQL query.

Comment: [`Cast<T>()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341406(v=vs.100).aspx) is a LINQ method. You're actually already using it here: `cmbEmp_Name.Items.Cast<ListItem>()` But yeah, looking again at the code, Jon Skeet's suggestion seems to be the better way to go (it usually is).

Comment: @JonSkeet: Updated the question. how to check the condition now ??

Comment: The same way as before: you put the condition in your SQL query. You're asking the database to match items based on conditions already - what makes you think that *this* condition is different?

Comment: @JonSkeet: It does not make think me it is different, let me try this and check whether it is working or not

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just filter the items before putting into `selectedItemstest` variable.

```
var selectedItemstest = cmbEmp_Name.Items.Cast<ListItem>()
                        .Where(x => x.Selected && x.Value.ToLower().Contains("processed"))
                        .Select(x => x.Value).ToArray();
```

Comment: what it will filter ?

Comment: If you select top 3 items in dropdown, this will return you only first item value because that is the only one processed. Did I get your question wrong? Let me know, I shall delete my answer in that case.

Comment: See, what I want is, if selected items contains text as `PROCESSED` then it should go inside the for loop other wise it should not

Comment: Doesn't it in other words mean the same what I told you already? If `selectedItemstest` has only the items with 'processed' text in them, you don't need `if` condition on `for` loop.

Comment: what If I select three items of which 2 are pending and 1 is `processed`. doesn't the for loop will execute for three times ??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110600/discussion-between-coder-and-nikhilvartak).

Comment: I don't think we should further discuss this. I don't see anything confusing here now. Your SQL (`in` clause) will give results for only the processed ones. Question is - Why don't you try this solution first?

Comment: I tried this, but in `IN` i get only `emp_card_no` not the status. Alsi I did `var selectedText = cmbEmp_Name.Items.Cast<ListItem>()
                        .Where(x => x.Selected && x.Value.ToLower().Contains("PROCESSED"))
                        .Select(x => x.Value).ToArray();


                    if (selectedText == "PROCESSED")
                    {` but its not working